# Azure Active Directory graph api : How to get users in the block of 1000, without using paging

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-powershell-v2

I am using Azure AD graph api to get all users of the organization. Using following get request to get all users

```
https://graph.windows.net/contoso.com/users?api-version=1.6
```

I am able to retrieve users using paging with the help of parameter `$skiptoken`

Is it possible to fire multiple such GET request without using $skiptoken and each GET request will return 1000 users.

For example
GET req 1 will retrieve users from 1 to 999

GET req 2 will retrieve users from 1000 to 1999

GET req 3 will retrieve users from 2000 to 2999

In short, I want to execute those requests over multiple threads instead of going sequentially when "$skiptoken" is used.

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot achieve that in other ways.**

According to your question, I think we can filter users with `$top`,like this:

Request:

`GET https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?$orderby=displayName&$top=999&api-version=1.6`

It returns a list of the first 999 users ordered by their display name.

However, it cannot filter the next 1000-1999 users just by the API when you filter top 1999 users, you need to filter by yourself. **Because  AAD Graph API doesn't support the option like `$skip`.**

But in this way, you can find the which user is the 1000th user and get the rest part users .

For more details about Supported queries, filters, and paging option in Azure AD Graph API, you can refer to [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options#PagingSupport).

You can also post your idea in [**this UserVoice Page**](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-active-directory?category_id=165567). The Azure AD Team will review it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
"But in this way, you can find the which user is the 1000th user and get the rest part users"  - Did you mean, if I know displayname of 1000th user then I can fetch next 1000 user after him ? How ?

Comment: Hi,@sagar. That's the point. It cannot do via API. I don't know your what your scenario is. You need to find the 999th user's displayname and read the rest data which starts with 1000 user by yourself. **e.g**. Copy data to text and find the `displayname` by `find`. Though it's a tough way...

Comment: @sagar You can't get entities in parallel like that sadly, only sequentially, as you probably already did.